# build is failing in sencha cmd with any of this command sencha ap watch/run/build, it started happening suddenly here is the log available

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd

## Exception information:

C:\Users\INTEL\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.2.0.84\plugin.xml:333: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\INTEL\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.2.0.84\ant\build\app\build-impl.xml:341: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\INTEL\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.2.0.84\ant\build\app\slice-impl.xml:378: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\INTEL\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.2.0.84\ant\build\app\slice-impl.xml:379: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\INTEL\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.2.0.84\ant\build\app\slice-impl.xml:107: com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The operation completed successfully.

```
 at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:121)
 at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.execute(PluginManager.java:104)
 at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeReverseFirst(PluginManager.java:145)
 at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:309)
 at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:729)
 at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands.java:125)
 at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:470)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
 at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:43)
 at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.dispatch(BasePluginCommands.java:289)
 at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
 at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
 at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:80)
 at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:151)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:84)
 at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
 at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)
```

Caused by: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\INTEL\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.2.0.84\ant\build\app\build-impl.xml:341: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\INTEL\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.2.0.84\ant\build\app\slice-impl.xml:378: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\INTEL\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.2.0.84\ant\build\app\slice-impl.xml:379: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\INTEL\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.2.0.84\ant\build\app\slice-impl.xml:107: com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The operation completed successfully.

```
 at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
 at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:117)
 at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.execute(PluginManager.java:104)
 at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeReverseFirst(PluginManager.java:145)
 at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:309)
 at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:729)
 at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands.java:125)
 at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:470)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
 at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:43)
 at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.dispatch(BasePluginCommands.java:289)
 at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
 at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
 at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:80)
 at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:151)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:84)
 at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
 at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)
```

Caused by: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\INTEL\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.2.0.84\ant\build\app\slice-impl.xml:378: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\INTEL\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.2.0.84\ant\build\app\slice-impl.xml:379: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\INTEL\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.2.0.84\ant\build\app\slice-impl.xml:107: com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: The operation completed successfully.

```
 at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
 at com.sencha.ant.CallTask.execute(CallTask.java:137)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
 at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be java runs out of memory. To increase the memory limit and generate more output try

```
sencha -i -J-Xms512m -J-Xmx3072m app ...
```

The error location `ant\build\app\slice-impl.xml:107` shows that the error occurs during [image slicing](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.0.0/guides/advanced_cmd/cmd_reference.html#advanced_cmd-_-cmd_reference_-_sencha_fs_slice) which is only needed for old IEs. You can probably turn it off.

```
// Test if slicing fails
sencha -i ant slice

// Turn off slicing temporarily
sencha -i config --prop skip.slice=0 then app build

// Turn off slicing permanently
echo "skip.slice=0" >> local.properties
```